# bash command to stop the program before sending email

Tags: bash

I currently have a scheduled job which executes and sends out emails if there are any alerts. Now, I need to change the job such that it will send out emails only when there are new alerts. I am using the below commands:

```
ALERT_COUNT=`ps -ef|grep myscript.pl|grep $alertCnt grep`

if [ $ALERT_COUNT -lt 0 ];
then exit 0; fi

echo "${EMAILBODY}" | mailx -r ${SENDER} -s "Alerts Email for $(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M)" abcd@xyz.com
```

Where $alertcnt is the variable to count the alerts inside my perl script.

But the job still completes execution and sends out email even if there are no new alerts.

I also tried the below options, but it didn't work:

```
ALERT_COUNT=`ps -ef|grep myscript.pl|grep $alertCnt grep`
Value="0"

if echo "$ALERT_COUNT" | grep -q "$Value"; then
    echo "No Alerts Found";
fi
```

Comment: if you create a script in bash with the below:   `ALERT_COUNT=\`ps -ef|grep myscript.pl|grep $alertCnt grep\`
echo $ALERT_COUNT`  what do you get when you run it?

Comment: I see this in CLI, when i run the command"grep myscript.pl | grep $alertCnt grep:   20877 117527  0 14:43 pts/63   00:00:00 grep myscript.pl

Comment: so that's not a number nor can it be compared to 0 which is why your script always runs

Comment: It's not obvious that this code *should* work. And... `grep $alertCnt grep`? What?

Comment: ...in general, it's a bad idea to count process-table entries (they're transient, they can be duplicated by programs having subshells or multiple threads, etc). And it's very unusual to have an "alert" be something that shows up in the process table.

Comment: ...if you really **do** want to count process table entries, though, don't grep through `ps` yourself -- use `pgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple solution would be to output the # of new alerts to a file that your bash script can then read into the function and act, if the # is greater than 0.

### count.txt

12

### emailer.sh

1. run perl script > output to count.txt
2. read line of count.txt > $COUNT
3. if $COUNT > 0 : continue, if not, exit
4. delete count.txt (makes sure you always have a single current value)